What causes these 2nd order knot shapes and why?
I twisted a (broken) rubber band around multiple revolutions. Initially it created what I call first order twists, where the "wave-length" of the twist got shorter and shorter across the entire length of the rubber band. At some point the first order twists saturated (probably due to the constraints of the compressive force, but I could be wrong here), and further twisting resulted in second order twist formation. However, as shown in the image below, there are two types of second order twists - a toroidal shape and a helical shape. What causes these two shapes to occur? Which is more likely to occur (and has the lowest energy)?
I do note that the toroidal shape is more likely to occur if I maintain a steady tension throughout, and the helical shape is more likely to occur if I relax the tension. Additionally, even with the tension kept steady and the toroidal shape growing, the helical shape could suddenly appear elsewhere along the rubber band, and then was the preferential growth location. Would this sort of double growth mechanisms have a similarity to some cell growth of materials?

